# How to Eliminate the Path from a Video Player's "Title"

Tags: javascript

Hi guys: This video player works great to play random video selections and display titles. However, the titles it displays include the title paths. How can it be changed so that it will just show the titles without the path and without the video extensions? Thanks

EDIT: I edited the selection names.

```
<video id="video" preload="auto" controls="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="playing">
</div>   <!-- Optional Titles -->



<script>
var video;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

var videoarr = ["https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Etude_Opus_10,_No._4_-_Chopin.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Fur_Elise_-_Beethoven.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Waltz_of_the_Flowers_-_Tchaikovsky.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Etude_Opus_10,_No._12_-_Chopin.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Alla_turca_-_Mozart.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Etude_Opus_10,_No._8_-_Chopin.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Piano_Sonata_No_16,_k545_-_Mozart.mp4", 
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Eine_Kleine_Nachtmusik_-_W._A._Mozart.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Rhapsody_in_Blue_-_George_Gershwin.mp4",
           ];
shuffle(videoarr);

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    video = $('video');
   
    len = videoarr.length;
    
    run(videoarr[current], video[0]);
    
    video[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
        }
        run(videoarr[current],audio[0]);
    });
}

function run(link, player){
        player.src = link;
        video[0].load();
        video[0].play(); /* play / pause*/
        $('#playing').html("<ul><li><a>" + link+ "</a></li></ul>");     
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I should've done this in the original post but now it will set the prepared link to whatever the shuffle function returns.

Short rundown:

-Use [`replace()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to take away the unwanted path and any underscores

-I also used [`substr()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) to cut off the ".mp4" from the end of the path as well (you could also use replace to take away the ".mp4" but I thought I would show you how both of these work)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<body>
   <video id="video" preload="auto" controls="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="playing">
</div>   <!-- Optional Titles -->


</body>
<script>



    var video;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

var videoarr = ["https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Etude_Opus_10,_No._4_-_Chopin.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Fur_Elise_-_Beethoven.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Waltz_of_the_Flowers_-_Tchaikovsky.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Etude_Opus_10,_No._12_-_Chopin.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Alla_turca_-_Mozart.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Etude_Opus_10,_No._8_-_Chopin.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Piano_Sonata_No_16,_k545_-_Mozart.mp4", 
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Eine_Kleine_Nachtmusik_-_W._A._Mozart.mp4",
            "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Rhapsody_in_Blue_-_George_Gershwin.mp4",
           ];
shuffle(videoarr);

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    video = $('video');
   
    len = videoarr.length;
    
    run(videoarr[current], video[0]);
    
    video[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
        }
        run(videoarr[current],audio[0]);
    });
}

function run(link, player){
        player.src = link;
        video[0].load();
        video[0].play(); /* play / pause*/


        //You can change the below replace with any part of the path you need
        preparedLink = link.replace('https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/', '')

        //You can user replace to replace all underscores with a space
        preparedLink = preparedLink.replace('_', ' ');
        
        //Take away the .mp3 with substr 
        preparedLink = preparedLink.substring(0, preparedLink.length-4);

        //Set new Link
        $('#playing').html("<ul><li><a href="+preparedLink+">" + preparedLink+ "</a></li></ul>");     
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply StrayAnt. I would like to eliminate  the path in the displayed title and also the underscores. For instance, how should  the substring be written to eliminate the path and the undersores from the following:

Comment: [code]https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Etude_Op_10,_No._4-_Chopin.mp4
https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Fur_Elise_-_Beethoven.mp4[/code]

Comment: I changed it the code so it only pulls the title/song. Substring is gunna be your firend on this one

Comment: Thank you again StrayAnt. But how can substring be intgrated into the script so that it will display the names of all the random files. As it is now, it displays Fur Elise as the name of every selection.

Comment: Sorry, should've made it like that to begin with. It now works with your code.. comments added throughout. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you again StrayAnt. That code works great to remove the path and extension of all selections. However, something is not allowing the underscores from being removed, whereas they were removed in your previous code.

Comment: This is how the music selections are now formatted:    `code`["https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Eine_Kleine_Nachtmusik_-_W._A._Mozart.mp4",
    "https://www.onlinepianoteacher.org/video-player/videos/Rhapsody_in_Blue_-_George_Gershwin.mp4",
               ]; `code`

Comment: @StyrayAnt Could you please take a look at code? The underscores are still not being removed and I can't figure our why. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate all underscores, not just the first one in the title, this line

```
preparedLink = preparedLink.replace("_", " ");
```

has to change to:

```
preparedLink = preparedLink.replace(/_/g, " ");
```